# How to compute the sum $\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n\Big(H_n^2-(\gamma+\log(n))^2\Big)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

How to compute the sum $$\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n\Big(H_n^2-(\gamma+\log(n))^2\Big)$$

I had computed some similar sums

$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n-\log(n)-\gamma}{n}$
and $\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n (H_n-\log(n)-\gamma)$

For the second one I considered to write it as $\sum_{n=1}^{2N}(-1)^n (H_n-\log(n)-\gamma)$

Break the sum up and Take $N$ to infinity

For the first one, the idea is to let $s\to 0$ and consider
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n-\log(n)-\gamma}{n^{1+s}}$$

and use Euler Macluarin formula of $\mathcal{H}(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n^s}$.

But for this one, my first idea is to use Euler-Boole instead, but it didn't work. I tried to break the sum up but it didn't work too.

Any help are appreciated

Comment: May be [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2377082p19459882) will help....